# How to blur ListView item with Blurry?

Tags: android, listview, blur, blurry

I want to blur a ListView items. I am blurring (using Blurry library) in CustomListViewAdapter's getView():

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        final AirdropResult airdrop = getItem(position);
        boolean bWasNull = false;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.result_item, parent, false);
            bWasNull = true;
        }

        final RelativeLayout airdropListRowInside = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.airdropListRowInside);

        final TextView tvName = (TextView) airdropListRowInside.findViewById(R.id.tvCoinName);
        final TextView tvDesc = (TextView) airdropListRowInside.findViewById(R.id.tvDesc);
        final TextView tvStartdate = (TextView) airdropListRowInside.findViewById(R.id.tvStartdate);

        tvName.setText(airdrop._name);
        tvDesc.setText(airdrop._shortdesc);

        if(bWasNull) {
            convertView.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Blurry.with(getContext())
                            .radius(5)
                            .sampling(2)
                            .async()
                            .animate(100)
                            .onto(airdropListRowInside);
                }
            });
        }

        return convertView;
    }
```

[image]

Seems like layout gets blurred but then it renders non-blurred layout on top (there is only one layout). I used Runnable [because it is apparently needed](https://github.com/wasabeef/Blurry/issues/25#issuecomment-198584382).

I am assuming this is because of how ListView reuses items but don't have enough understanding to solve it. Can someone help?

Comment: Post full `getView()`  method

Comment: Posted full implementation.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `bWasNull` is defined inside `getView()`. so it is always being reset to `false` when the `getView()` being called again, this time `convertView` in not `null` so `bWasNull` is not being true and Blurry is not being applied for new `convertView`.

Define `bWasNull` outside of `getView()`. B.T.W I don't see the use of this `bWasNull`.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem. If I do the blurring everytime `getView()` is called, then it gets blurred multipletimes and I get smudged-black-color-like effect.